# Error in Book? Need help

Tags: translation, meaning, mandarin, usage, characters

I was reading Assimil Chinese with Ease and came across this.

你见过他？

Since this is a question, is 吗 necessary for the question? Perhaps an error? Or can you omit 吗？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can omit the "吗", but:

In writing, you need a question mark.

In speech, a rising intonation must be used.

Answer (score 3):

fefe is right in that omitting "吗" is allowed, but they have slightly different meanings:

你见过他？has a bit of on the rhetorical sense in it, and seems more surprised - it can be somewhat close to "You've met him, really?" or "Oh, you have ever met him?"

你见过他吗？is more of a question, as in purely asking "Have you ever met him, or not?"